# Core data - how to fetch results with filter of another entity

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

i would like to fetch results from entity and filter the result with attribute from another entity.

i have an 2 entities:

*Users{user_id,first_name,last_name}*

*UsersPhoneNumbers{phone_id,user_id, phone_number}*

in SQL it should look like this:

```
select * from Users where Users.user_id in (select user_id from UsersPhoneNumbers where phone_number = '+972-54-...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to add a relation between your User entity and UsersPhoneNumbers.

I.e. it'll look like this:

`Users{user_id,first_name,last_name,phone_number}`

`UsersPhoneNumbers{phone_id,user,phone_number}`

Then use a fetch request based on this relationship:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone_number.phone_number like[cd] %@",  @"+972-54*"];
NSArray* users = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: How do i add relation between the attributes?                Users.user_id->UserPhoneNumbers.user_id

Comment: @RonFridman, in your data model file (xcdatamodel), you want to add a new "Relationship" to your Users entity. Set its name as "phone_number", destination as "UserPhoneNumbers". Do the same for your UserPhoneNumbers. Then set the "inverse" when both are defined (you'll get a warning if you don't set these - this automatically adds back references - so for instance, if you set user.phone_number, phoneNumber.user gets set automatically). I'd recommend checking out the [CoreData reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)